# Regex to march vowels not in certain word

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to highlight vowels for a simple reading aid website.

I have some HTML and want to highlight vowels, but there's also some HTML that I don't want to mess with. Basically only just `<mark data-trigger="">other word</mark>`

To clarify.

I have this:

```
Hello, this is a <mark data-trigger="">word</mark> that is in the text. I 
want to get all vowels and wrap it in spans, but avoid messing with the other 
html.
```

I want this:

```
H<span>e</span>ll<span>o</span>, th<span>i</span>s <span>i</span>s a <mark data-trigger="">word</mark> th<span>a</span>t...
```

I know this replaces all vowels > `replace(/(a|e|i|o|u)/ig, "<span class='vowel'>$1</span>")`

It would be enough to add "don't mess with anything inside MARK tags"

Can I achieve this using RegExp?

I can use external libraries, jQuery or whatever.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 ???

Comment: Given that sample, can you show what the expected result would be? Also: '*It would be enough to add "don't mess with anything inside s"*' - what is 's'?

Comment: What is the input string?

Comment: @ashawley Hey! Thanks, I think I was aware that you cannot parse html with regex, but this is really a small amount of tags and different strings going in there. Also, I can use external libraries or other solutions, Regex was just what came to mind.

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry, editor messed with my html tags. I meant I wanted to keep the regex from matching inside the MARK html tags.
I also added sample and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This should capture all vowels not included in the html tags and not inside of the tags as well.

`/(a|e|i|o|u)|(?:<.*?>.*<\/.*?>)/g`

If you did want to capture the text inside the html tags it would be this.

`/(a|e|i|o|u)|(?:<.*?>)/g`

Comment: This assumes the HTML only contains inline elements and no nested elements?  For example, `<div><p>Tags <em>inside</em> other tags</p></div>`

Comment: Hey! I think this matches also stuff inside the tags. I've tried it in code and here http://www.regextester.com/15 and it gets text inside the marks :/

Comment: The top solution ignores html tags and their contents. https://regex101.com/r/sDB3TX/1